# 20GB SSD + 320GB HDD. Save SSD Space

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, storage

I have a Acer Aspire S3. It has a 20GB SSD and a 320GB HDD. I want to install Ubuntu on my small SSD and all my data on the larger HDD. I was wondering what can I store on my HDD to save as much space on my SSD? Also will I be ok running Ubuntu on only 20GB?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest having the home folder on the HDD. That's where all your personal data is stored, like music, pictures, videos, bookmarks, etc, as well as user configuration files. All of that together can take a lot of space, and has no reason to be on the SSD.

Optional:

Another candidate is `/var`. It doesn't take that much space - a few hundred MB or so, but contains the logs and some caches.